# How to implement / register singleton HttClientFactory in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, .net-standard

I am using Xamarin Forms with Prism.

How can I register a service for HttpClientFactory?
Is there a equivalent in xamarin/prism to the ConfigureServices method in .net core?

I would like to use the equivalent of this code in Xamarin forms:

```
    services.AddHttpClient<MyClient>("MyHttpClient",
        x => { x.BaseAddress = new Uri("example.com"); }
        ).AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());
    services.AddSingleton<MyClientFactory>();
```

I have been trying different ways and I cannot find the right way to do it.

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**

I have got these clases in a netstandard ClassLibrary called **BusinessLogic**

MyClientFactory.cs:

```
namespace BusinessLogic.Services
{
    public class MyClientFactory
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public MyClientFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public MyClient Create()
        {
            return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyClient>();
        }
    }
}
```

MyClient.cs:

```
namespace ServiceBusinessLogic.Services
{
    public class MyClient : IMyClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly ILogger<MyClient> _logger;

        public MyClient(ILogger<MyClient> logger, HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
        }

        public async Task<Result<Token>> GetToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string userName, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "Token");
                request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", userName),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
                });

                HttpResponseMessage result = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("the status code is: {0}", (int)result.StatusCode);

// CODE abbreviated for reading

        }
```

Interface IMyClient.cs:

```
namespace MyBusinessLogic.Services
{
    public interface IMyClient
    {
        Task<Result<Token>> GetToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string userName, string password);
    // CODE abbreviated for reading
```

MyClientQueries.cs:

```
namespace MyBusinessLogic.Services
{
    public class MyClientQueries
    {
        private readonly MyClientFactory _myClientFactory;

        public MyClientQueries(MyClientFactory myClientFactory)
        {
            _MyClientFactory = myClientFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myClientFactory));

        }

        public async Task<Result<Token>> GetToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string username, string password)
        {
            var mysClient = _myClientFactory.Create();
            var response = await tsClient.GetToken(cancellationToken, username, password).ConfigureAwait(true);

            return response;
        }
// CODE abbreviated
```

Then I have got a xamarin forms Project with Prism called **App_Mobile_test**

App.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
         public App() : this(null) { }

        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

        protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage>();

        }
    }
```

I would like to use **MyClientQueries** which uses DI for **HttpClientFactory** and **HttpClient** in the Xamarin Forms project as a service (singleton) so I can call GetToken and all the other methods that are in that class.

But I do not know how to do this in Xamarin Forms.

MyBusinessProject that contains MyClientQueries which I want to use, is already used in a asp.net core mvc and the services were added in the startup.cs in .net core like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
#region "api service"  

            services.AddSingleton<MyClientQueries>();

            services.AddHttpClient<MyClient>("MyHttpClient", 
                x => { x.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["APIConfiguration:BaseAddress"]); }
                ).AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());

            services.AddSingleton<MyClientFactory>();

            #endregion
//CODE abbreviated
}
```

How can I register the same objects I am doing in the .net Core app, but in Xamarin Forms and use the dependency injection for the view models?
The shared project "MyBusinessLogic" works fine in the asp.net core, and I would like to reuse this project in the Xamarin project. Specially MyClientQueries which has got HttpClientFactory dependency.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the different ways you tried, each with a description of what went wrong e.g. exception or unintended behaviour...

Comment: yes but I have deleted all changes and trying dependency injection with registerTypes with Prism. The main question is how I can create a singleton in the RegisterTypes() that uses HttpClientFactory. The equivalent of the snippet code but in RegisterTypes method in App.xaml. Hope it makes sense

Comment: I will update the question with more code.

Comment: @Haukinger I have added all the code I have at the moment. I updated the main post.

Comment: @Dgg Did you get anywhere with this? Trying the same thing...very little around by way of documentation.

Comment: @ledragon there is not a lot of documentation. check this link https://montemagno.com/add-asp-net-cores-dependency-injection-into-xamarin-apps-with-hostbuilder/

Comment: @Dgg thanks for your reply...I saw that post but I really haven't managed to get this working get after multiple attempts. I'm using refit also and the problem seems to be with registering refit client as a service. Did you manage to get it all working?

Comment: @ledragon I tried this sample and followed it but I am not working on this project just yet. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/VS2019-FirstXamarinApp hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on what DI you are using as to what the syntax will be, but generally that sort of code will be in the App constructor or a method called by the constructor.

So for example you might have a method called RegisterServices in your App.xaml.cs that is called from the constructor, after the Xamarin Init() has been called.

Inside that RegisterServices Method you would have something like this:

```
   FreshIOC.Container.Register<IHttpManager, HttpManager>().AsSingleton();
```

We use FreshMvvm which uses TinyIOC for Dependancy Injection, so the syntax may differ, but the concept will be the same.

Comment: thank you yes. There is RegisterServices in the app.xaml, but I do not know how to write a similar code to the snippet I posted in the question. Is it possible to use something like AddHttpClient does?  containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton.... and add the base address

Comment: @Dgg could you not just add that in to the constructor for the HttpClient?

Comment: @Dgg what IOC container are you using with Prism?

Comment: I was looking at https://prismlibrary.com/docs/dependency-injection/registering-types.html and register HttpClientFactory.

I have a class in a Net Standard Class Library project which implements all the calls to the API. I wanted to make it available in view models. The problem I found was I did not know how to register/assign "MyClientFactory" which relies on DI to get the httpclient. something like the code I posted (it is what my .net core app is using). Maybe the way is to create an interface in xamarin that calls MyClientFactory and resolve the HttpClient... a bit lost.

Comment: I have updated the top question with a lot of code. Thank you